# Referring to Kubernetes Docker registry secrets with namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**What I have**

I have used Kube secrets for private Docker registry authentication in the `default` namespace. That works as expected. For example:

```
$ kubectl get secret regsecret
NAME        TYPE                             DATA      AGE
regsecret   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1         30m
```

Which is referenced in my `deployment.yml` as shown in the snippet below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  bootstrap-nginx
        image: quay.io/example/nginx:latest
      ...
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
```

**Here's my question**

I need to create the `regsecret` above in a `namepsace`, for example, `myns` as shown below:

```
$ kubectl get secret regsecret --namespace=myns
NAME        TYPE                             DATA      AGE
regsecret   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1         30m
```

With this, how do I reference `regsecret` from `myns` namespace into my deployment spec? If I use `imagePullSecrets` as shown above, it fails saying that Kubernetes could not pull the image (the secret `regsecret` could not be found). Is there a way to reference "fully qualified" secret name in `imagePullSecrets`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, there is no way to accomplish this. You will need to create the `regsecret` in the same namespace where your Deployment is.

> `ImagePullSecrets` is an optional list of references to secrets **in the same
>        namespace** to use for pulling any of the images used by this PodSpec. If
>        specified, these secrets will be passed to individual puller
>        implementations for them to use. For example, in the case of docker, only
>        DockerConfig type secrets are honored.

See also:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod